# Pandas: Finding the average of every next 10 data points in CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large datasets:

```
Time,   Value
01.01.2018 00:00:00.000,  5.1398
01.01.2018 00:01:00.000,  5.1298
01.01.2018 00:02:00.000,  5.1438
01.01.2018 00:03:00.000,  5.1228
01.01.2018 00:04:00.000,  5.1168
.... , ,,,,
31.12.2018 23:59:59.000,  6.3498
```

The data is a `minute` data from the `first` day of the year to the `last` day of the year

I want to use `Pandas` to find the average of every 5 days. For example:

Average from `01.01.2018 00:00:00.000` to `05.01.2018 23:59:59.000` for `05.01.2018`

The next average will be from `02.01.2018 00:00:00.000` to `6.01.2018 23:59:59.000` for `06.01.2018`

The next average will be from `03.01.2018 00:00:00.000` to `7.01.2018 23:59:59.000` for `07.01.2018`

and so on...

> For a given day, there are 24hours * 60minutes =  1440 data points. So I need to get the average of 1440 data points * 5 days = 7200 data points.

The final DataFrame will look like this:

```
Time,   Value
05.01.2018,  5.1398
06.01.2018,  5.1298
07.01.2018,  5.1438
.... , ,,,,
31.12.2018,  6.3498
```

The bottom line is to calculate the average of data from today to the past 5 days and the average value is shown as above.

I tried to iterate through Python loop but I wanted something better than we can do from Pandas.

Comment: `rolling(5).mean()`?

Comment: `rolling(5).mean()` gave promising output. I also need to add, time, avg in a DataFrame, just like the final DataFrame output above.

Comment: @QuangHoang: I updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated that you have data for **every** minute, i.e. there's always the same number of values per day (1440), then you can simply take the daily means and then the means of a 5-day rolling window on these daily means.

Example (value is running minute number in year, starting with 0):

```
s = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31 23:59', freq='1T'))
df = pd.DataFrame(s.index.values, index=s, columns=['Value'])
df.groupby(df.index.floor('d'))['Value'].mean().rolling(5).mean().dropna()
```

Result:

```
2018-01-05      3599.5
2018-01-06      5039.5
2018-01-07      6479.5
2018-01-08      7919.5
                ...   
2018-12-28    517679.5
2018-12-29    519119.5
2018-12-30    520559.5
2018-12-31    521999.5
```

Answer (score 3):

#### IIUC

You want to do rolling mean then resample it daily.

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Time=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-7 23:59', freq='12H')
)).assign(Value=lambda d: np.arange(len(d)))

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df = df.set_index('Time')

df

                 Value
Time                      
2018-01-01 00:00:00      0
2018-01-01 12:00:00      1
2018-01-02 00:00:00      2
2018-01-02 12:00:00      3
2018-01-03 00:00:00      4
2018-01-03 12:00:00      5
2018-01-04 00:00:00      6
2018-01-04 12:00:00      7
2018-01-05 00:00:00      8
2018-01-05 12:00:00      9
2018-01-06 00:00:00     10
2018-01-06 12:00:00     11
2018-01-07 00:00:00     12
2018-01-07 12:00:00     13
```

#### Solution

Interesting thing when you roll by time window is that Pandas doesn't know about when you've begun a full rolling period.  Consequentially, `df.rolling('5D').mean()` will start taking the mean immediately.  You can solve this by trimming the first 5 days (or 4 days) which we take take of after resampling daily.

```
df.rolling('5D').mean().resample('D').last().iloc[4:]

            Value
Time             
2018-01-05    4.5
2018-01-06    6.5
2018-01-07    8.5
```

Comment: I have updated the question for clarity. For a given day, there are 24hours * 60minutes =  1440 data points. So I need to get the average of 1440 data points * 5 days = 7200 data points and so on for the next day...